# How to delete duplicated rows on one file based on a common field between two files with AWK?

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files

1. File 1 contains 3 fields
2. File 2 contains 4 fields

The number of rows of File 1 is much smaller than that of File 2

I would like to compare between two files based on 1st field with the following operation

*If the first field in any row of file 1 appears in the first field of a row in file 2, don't print that row for file 2.*

Any advice would be grateful.

```
Input File 1

 S13109 3739 31082 
 S45002 3800 31873 
 S43722 3313 26638 

Input File 2

 S13109 3738 31081 0 
 S13109 3737 31080 0 
 S00033 3008 29985 0 
 S00033 3007 29984 0 
 S00022 4130 31838 0 
 S00022 4129 31837 0 
 S00188 3317 27372 0 
 S45002 3759 31832 0 
 S45002 3758 31831 0 
 S45002 3757 31830 0 
 S43722 3020 26345 0 
 S43722 3019 26344 0 
 S00371 3737 33636 0 
 S00371 3736 33635 0 

Desired Output

 S00033 3008 29985 0 
 S00033 3007 29984 0
 S00022 4130 31838 0 
 S00022 4129 31837 0 
 S00188 3317 27372 0
 S00371 3737 33636 0 
 S00371 3736 33635 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}!a[$1]' file1 file2`

How it works:

```
FNR==NR
```

When you have two (or more) input files to awk, `NR` will reset back to 1 on the first line of the next file whereas `FNR` will continuing incrementing from where it left off.  By checking `FNR==NR` we are essentially checking to see if we are currently parsing the first file.

```
a[$1]++
```

If we *are* parsing the first file (see above) then create an associative array with the first field `$1` as the key and post increment the value by 1.  This essentially lets us create a 'seen' list.

```
next
```

This command tells awk not to process any further commands and to read in the next record and start over.  We do this because file1 is only meant to set the associative array

```
!a[$1]
```

This line only executes when `FNR==NR` is false, i.e. we are *not* parsing file1 and thus must be parsing file2.  We then use the first field `$1` of file2 as the key to index into our 'seen' list created earlier.  If the value returned is 0 it means we didn't see it in file1 and therefore we should print this line.  Conversely, if the value is non-zero then we *did* see it in file1 and thus we should *not* print its value. Note that `!a[$1]` is equivalent to `!a[$1]{print}` because the default action when one is not given is to print the entire line.

Comment: Dear SiegeX. Your explanation is very instructive for a beginner like me. The problem I have with writing this kind of script is that there are many approaches to do the same task, but the optimum one is difficult to achieve. I guess it comes with experience. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: FNR reinitializes for each file. NR keeps incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to preserve the order of the lines, you can use process substitution in Bash, Korn shell or Z shell along with the `join` and `sort` utilities:

```
join -v 2 <(sort file_1) <(sort file_2)
```

If you're using a shell without process substitution you would have to pre-sort the files.