# How to compare two files' strings without numbers

Tags: python, string

I have two files, file1 contains contents as

```
aaa  
bbb  
ccc
```

and file 2 contains contents as

```
ccc 2
ddd 10
eee 11
aaa 12
rrr 3
bbb 20
nnn 46
```

I would like to do like this, if file2 contains file1's line, then that line would be removed from file2. At last, file2 will be as

```
ddd 10
eee 11
rrr 3
nnn 46
```

Besides, my code is

```
f1 = open("test1.txt","r")
f2 = open("test2.txt","r")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()
f1.close()
f2.close()
outFile = open("test.txt","w")
x = 0
for i in fileOne:
    if i !=  fileTwo[x]:
    outFile.writelines(fileTwo[x])
    x += 1

outFile.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383415/how-to-delete-duplicated-rows-on-one-file-based-on-a-common-field-between-two-fi but in Python?

Comment: If your code isn't working, explain the nature of the error.  If it is, why are you here?

Comment: you are assuming both files are sorted.

Answer (score 3):

A `set` is best here:

```
with open(file1) as f1:
    s = set(x.strip() for x in f1)

with open(file2) as f2, open(fileout,'w') as fout:
    for line in f2:
        if line.split(None,1)[0] not in s:
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is working, just replace:

```
if i !=  fileTwo[x]
```

by

```
if not i in fileTwo[x]
```

You can use [startswith()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) too